# I cant get rspec autotest to working? (Ruby, no rails)

Tags: ruby, rspec, autotest

I have a basic ruby project :-

```
$ tree
.
├── Gemfile
├── lib
│   ├── checkout.rb
│   └── item.rb
├── README.md
└── test
    ├── checkout_spec.rb
    └── item_spec.rb
```

Which can run the rspec tests :-

```
$ rspec test/*_spec.rb
....

Finished in 0.18797 seconds
4 examples, 0 failures
```

But who wants to up-arrow and press enter every sec, I wanted autotest...

But when I run it, it doesn't find my tests!

```
$ autotest -vw
No tests matched Gemfile
No tests matched README.md
No tests matched lib/checkout.rb
No tests matched lib/item.rb
No tests matched test/checkout_spec.rb
No tests matched test/item_spec.rb
```

Then I start saving files :-

```
{"lib/checkout.rb"=>2011-12-07 22:06:04 +0000}
No tests matched lib/checkout.rb
{"lib/checkout.rb"=>2011-12-07 22:06:04 +0000}
No tests matched lib/checkout.rb
{"test/.goutputstream-NQC45V"=>2011-12-07 22:06:20 +0000}
No tests matched test/.goutputstream-NQC45V
{"test/.goutputstream-NQC45V"=>2011-12-07 22:06:20 +0000}
No tests matched test/.goutputstream-NQC45V
{"lib/checkout.rb"=>2011-12-07 22:06:45 +0000}
No tests matched lib/checkout.rb
{"lib/checkout.rb"=>2011-12-07 22:06:45 +0000}
No tests matched lib/checkout.rb
<just sits here
```

I've read about `.autotest` and `spec_helper.rb`, but can seem to home in on the correct search/page?

---

Edit: A well spotted mismatch between the help and my layout spotted by the tin man.

But changing my `test` to `tests` did not help!:-

```
No tests matched tests/checkout_spec.rb
No tests matched tests/item_spec.rb
No tests matched tests/rule_parser_spec.rb
No tests matched tests/runner.rb
No tests matched tests/spec_helper.rb
{"lib/rule_parser.rb"=>2011-12-08 07:24:29 +0000}
No tests matched lib/rule_parser.rb
{"lib/rule_parser.rb"=>2011-12-08 07:24:29 +0000}
No tests matched lib/rule_parser.rb
{"tests/checkout_spec.rb"=>2011-12-08 07:24:35 +0000}
No tests matched tests/checkout_spec.rb
{"tests/checkout_spec.rb"=>2011-12-08 07:24:35 +0000}
No tests matched tests/checkout_spec.rb
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should change it to spec. I don't use autotest but the latest versions of rspec assume you have a spec dir in to root of your project. So should autotest I guess.

Answer (score 2):

I changed the directory to `spec`!

Now both work! :-

```
rspec
autotest
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `test` directory to `tests`. That should make autotest happier.

From `autotest --help`:

> It assumes the code is in lib, and tests are in tests.

Comment: Ah, looked like a winner, but, alas no, I've updated the OP to show the code output.

Comment: Umm I think you should change it to spec. I don't use autotest but the latest versions of rspec assume you have a spec dir in to root of your project. So should autotest I guess.

Comment: @lucapette for some reason, I completely ignored your reply! Hence my post is exactly what you put! You should make it an answer and I'll accept it!